# How can I pass a predefined variable into an awk column function?

Tags: awk

I'd like to pass a predefined variable as the column number for an awk script. I've stripped out the unnecessary bits and below is an example of what I'd like to get done. Further below is a portion of what I've tried so far.

Reason: This is a semi-long script that currently works though I'd like to define the columns early in the script as this would make the script much easier to update as columns change.

I'd like for the "state" variable to be passed on to awk's column identifier, eg:

```sh
#/bin/bash

export state='$6'


cat ~/file | awk -v column="$state" 'state!="FAILED"'
```

Running the above code produces rows that do indeed have column 6 as "FAILED", so there must be something wrong. While `awk '$6!="FAILED"'` works as expected

Different things I've tried so far:

1. defining $state as 6 rather than '$6' and including the $ in the awk != command.
2. `awk '{ENVIRON["state"]!="FAILED"}'`, with the same modifications as 1

Comment: Rename `column` to `awkvar` and `state` to `shellvar`. Now do you see what your problem is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
state=6
cat ~/file | awk -v column="$state" '$column != "FAILED"'
```

`$var` in awk will get the field specified by the value of variable `var`.
So, `$NF` will get the last field. Note that the awk variable here is `column`, *not* `state`.

For example:

```
% seq 1 20 | paste - - - -
1   2   3   4
5   6   7   8
9   10  11  12
13  14  15  16
17  18  19  20
% seq 1 20 | paste - - - - | awk -v column=3 '{print $column}'
3
7
11
15
19
```

Comment: you don't need `cat` there, awk can read files on its own. other than that lgtm